# Dropdown menu imported inside a div (with jquery .load) doesn't work, why?

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, load

I'm using the `.load()` jquery function to import a document inside a `div`.
Inside the imported document there is a form with a `<select>` tag.
The menu bar appears, but if I click on it the dropdown menu doesn't appear .

If i use the `<select>` OUT of the `div` (out the containor), the dropdown menu starts well.

What shouldI do?

Answer (score 1):

As you're loading content dynamically, the click function doesn't work as the dropdown wasn't there in the first place on DOM ready.

Try changing your

```
.click(function() {}
```

to

```
.on('click', function() {}
```

Should work.